# MSBuild Project: Get item list from another project and print foreach

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

For example, there are two projects:

```
Main.Proj

<MyCustomItemHa Include="path1"/>
<MyCustomItemHa Include="path2"/>
<MyCustomItemHa Include="path3"/>
```

And there is a separate project

```
Secondary.Proj

<Target Name="Printtt">
**   How can I execute <Message here for each of paths imported above? **
**   To Get output equivalent to: **
**     <Message Text="path1" />     **
**     <Message Text="path2" />     **
**     <Message Text="path3" />      **
**   for each MyCustomItemHa  from Main.Proj **
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild is a declarative language and has no loops. There is no foreach loop in MSBuild.

You can use task batching - see [MSBuild batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022).

As an example, the code

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Fruit Include="Apple" />
        <Fruit Include="Banana" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="DisplayFruit">
        <Message Text="%(Fruit.Identity)" />
    </Target>
```

will display

```
         Apple
         Banana
```

Two separate projects can't 'see' each other and can't get an `ItemGroup` from each other. But you can create a common file that defines the `ItemGroup` and each project can [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) the common file.